# Non Perl files that need to be installed with CPAN distribution?

Tags: perl, cpan

I need to have files installed with my CPAN dist that aren't Perl. Where in the dist should I put them? and what's the best way to reference them from within a module so that I have access to them regardless of users configuration?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, you're not very clear on what these files are and how they're used, but you're probably looking for [File::ShareDir](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::ShareDir).

File::ShareDir only takes care of the run-time access to the files from your module.  The way you get the files installed along with your module depends on which install system you use:

- If you use [Dist::Zilla](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Dist::Zilla), you use its [ShareDir](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Dist::Zilla::Plugin::ShareDir) plugin, which has an undocumented `dir` parameter that defaults to `share`.
- For [Module::Build](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Module::Build), you use the [share_dir](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Module::Build::API#share_dir) parameter.
- For [Module::Install](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Module::Install), you use the [install_share](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Module::Install::API#install_share) command.
- [ExtUtils::MakeMaker](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?ExtUtils::MakeMaker) doesn't have built in support, but you can use the [File::ShareDir::Install](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::ShareDir::Install) module to add it.

Comment: does the DZP have a default directory to throw stuff in?

Comment: @xenoterracide, it's not properly documented, but if you look at the source, there's a `dir` parameter that defaults to `share`.  Dzil's ShareDir plugin only supports dist-level files at the current time.

Comment: as for what I'm using it for... [my question before this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7263767/206466) should clarify that. Unless someone tells me they should not be shipped with the dist, this seems like the correct way to do it.

Comment: might be worth mentioning [File::ShareDir::PathClass](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-ShareDir-PathClass/lib/File/ShareDir/PathClass.pm)

Comment: @xenoterracide, I hadn't noticed that one.  I'm not sure it really adds enough value to be worth installing another module, though.

Comment: These days I use [File::ShareDir::ProjectDistDir](https://metacpan.org/module/File::ShareDir::ProjectDistDir) for this purpose